# Updating useState object values with map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using useState inside of useContext, I have a button inside of a component that when the user clicks the button it will add a new element on the page which in return it will create a new object in the useState array like so:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems((items) => [...items, {
      id: items.length,
      key: randomKey(),
      selected: false,
      FG_value: 0,
      FS_value: 0,
      FB_value: 'auto',
      AS_value: 'auto',
      OR_value: 0,
    }])
  }
```

Now when a user clicks on an element on the page, it will toggle the "selected" value false/true like this:

```
  const editItem = (value) => {
    const selectedItem = items.map((item) => item.key === value ? {
      ...item,
      selected: !item.selected
    } : item)
    setItems(selectedItem)
  }
```

The above code works like it should, but where im getting stuck is that when a user clicks on an element and then clicks to a different element, both elements "selected" values are true. I'm trying to correctly write the code so that if an element is clicked and the `item.key === value`, then toggle the "selected" and set all other `items.selected` values to false. So basically if the user clicks the first element, that one is selected, then if they click a different element, it deselects the first element then selects the new clicked element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like CertainPerformance, I would keep separate state for the selected item. However, if you wanted to modify your `editItem` function to toggle one item (from selected to unselected or unselected to selected) and make all other items unselected (i.e. selected is `false`), then you can write it like this:

```js
const editItem = (value) => {
  const updatedItems = items.map((item) => item.key === value ? {
    ...item,
    selected: !item.selected
  } : {
    ...item,
    selected: false
  })
  setItems(updatedItems)
}
```

I renamed `selectedItem` to `updatedItems` because `selectedItem` made it seem like the variable was only for one item when it was actually for all items.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question and works without having to re-write any other code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, rather than structuring your state such that each item has a selected property, create a separate state for the selected item. Then it's as simple as setting that state to the selected item's key or index.

If the items don't get removed from the array, you could do:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const [selectedItemIndex, setSelectedItemIndex] = useState(-1);
// ...
{items.map((item, i) => (
  <other item JSX>
  <button onClick={() => setSelectedItemIndex(i === selectedItemIndex ? -1 : i)}
))}
```

Now, wherever you use `item.selected` currently, instead compare the index of the item being iterated over against the `selectedItemIndex`.

Comment: I will agree the correct way to do it would be to have its own state and update it like you suggested, but my project is a little more complex than the snippets of code I proved. I will have to write a bunch of code in order to get it working correctly, which I will end up doing.